# Using Packwerk with ActiveAdmin (unitialized constant after moving model folder)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using [packwerk](https://github.com/Shopify/packwerk) in my rails 6 application to enforce boundaries between new components (but I think the problem is more related to moving a model being used by active admin out of the `app/models` folder).

Old setup of rails project:

```
app/
 ...
 models/
  subscription.rb
 ...
 services/
  subscription_service.rb
bin
config
...
```

Becomes

```
app
bin
components/
  subscription/ 
    app/
      public/
        subscription_service.rb
  spec/
    subscription_service_spec.rb
  package.yml
config
...
```

I then autoload the public files in my `config/application.rb`

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root / "components/*/app/public"]
  ...
end
```

Now when I run `bundle exec rspec components/subscriptions/spec/subscription_service_spec.rb` the tests pass and all seems to work fine.

When I add the subscription model though so that structure will look like this:

```
app
bin
components/
  subscription/ 
    app/
      public/
        subscription_service.rb
  models/
    subscription.rb # no longer in app/models
  spec/
    subscription_service_spec.rb
  package.yml
config
...
```

I get this error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./components/subscriptions/spec/subscription_service_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  ActiveAdmin.register Subscription do
    menu false

    includes :pauses, :invoices

    config.remove_action_item(:edit)
    config.remove_action_item(:destroy)

    filter :id
    filter :status

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Subscription
```

I think this has something to do with how ActiveAdmin autoloads perhaps, but I'm struggling to find an answer - so any help/clues would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out, I forgot to import the models folder in `application.rb` which should now look like:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root / "components/*/app/public"]
  config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root / "components/*/models"]
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this a few years later, I used [packs-rails](https://github.com/rubyatscale/packs-rails) but had to add the following my active admin initialiser:

```rb
config.load_paths << File.join(Rails.root, "packages", "*", "app", "admin")
```

Also in `config/application.rb`:

```rb
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore("#{Rails.root}/packages/*/app/admin")
```

You may need to replace `packages` with your own top level name.